# ngx datatable custom footer own component

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I want to use custom footer everywhere for my tables:
http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#footer

The issue that I do not want to define html every time in every component, so I want to create my own component `<app-custom-footer` that will be a wrapper for default:

```
<ngx-datatable-footer>
```

And then use like:

```
<ngx-datatable
        class="material"
        [rows]="rows"
        [columns]="columns"
        [columnMode]="ColumnMode.force"
        [footerHeight]="100"
        [headerHeight]="50"
        rowHeight="auto"
      >
      <app-custom-footer [rows]="rows"><a/pp-custom-footer>
      </ngx-datatable>
    </div>
```

Is there a way to achieve this ?